# Generate a Liferay Portlet from a Ruby On Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liferay, portlet, war

I wanted to know if it exists a plugin or something similar to obtain a WAR to deploy as a Liferay Portlet from a Ruby On Rails application.

I'm really interested on it, because I tried the [sample-ruby-portlet](http://www.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Developing+Ruby+Portlets+in+Liferay) and it liked me a lot, but I want to create that portlets automatically from my RoR applications. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: I tried it with **[this guide](http://rails-portlet.rubyforge.org/)**, but following the **[next steps](https://github.com/lamikae/rails-portlet/blob/master/example/README.md)**, afer 'git submodule update', it fails me on 'caterpillar portlets'. The error message is: **rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper** Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use Rake, in conjunction with the Warbler gem or something, to automatically generate the WAR file.

Comment: With Warbler I can create a war, but I don't only want to deploy a RoR in a Tomcat, I want to generate a portlet with mi RoR application to deploy into Liferay, making part of the portal. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I don't know. What do you need for that beside a WAR file?

Comment: I want portlet creation but I want to develop that portlets with Ruby on Rails

Comment: According to http://docs.liferay.com/portal/4.2/official/liferay-portlet-development-guide-4.2/onepage/ , the portlet is just a WAR file. So Warbler should, I think, be all you need.